# offsetParent() not working correctly?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML document structure setup:

```
<li class="item-i">I</li>
<li class="item-ii" style="position: relative;">II
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>
        <li class="item-b">B
            <ul class="level-3">
                <li class="item-1">1</li>
                <li class="item-2">2</li>
                <li class="item-3">3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">C</li>
        <li class="item-d">D
            <ul class="alpha">
                <li class="alpha-1">Alpha 1</li>
                <li class="alpha-2">Alpha 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-e">E</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-iii">III</li>

    <input id="Set" type="button" value="Click">
```

So for my understanding of the offsetParent is:  given alpha-1, the offset parent should be alpha.  So I'm trying to create a simple background/border around it with the following jquery snippet

```
$('#Set').click(function() {
    $("li.alpha-1").offsetParent().addClass("greyMe");
});
```

I do get the effect that I wanted but *not* where I thought it would be.  You can see a demo of it here.  http://jsfiddle.net/coson/DGHwb/9/

How can I get it to highlight everything in the  element whose class = "alpha"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getOffsetParent()` returns the closest ancestor element that is positioned.  Since `item-ii` is the first position element in the set of ancestors it is given the class.  Since `ul.alpha` is not positioned it is not selected by `getOffsetparent()`.

To select `.alpha` you can use `.parents(".alpha")`:

```
$('#Set').click(function() {
    $("li.alpha-1").parents(".alpha").addClass("greyMe");
});
```

Or if there is only one element with class `.alpha`, its more simple:

```
$('#Set').click(function() {
    $(".alpha").addClass("greyMe");
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DGHwb/11/